# Use JSON.stringify but the data still have array, what does it mean?

Tags: json

I have a data which are object array. It contains object arrays in a tree structure. I use JSON.stringify(myArray) but the data still contain array because I see [] inside the converted data.

In my case, I want all the data to be converted into json object not array regarding I need to used the data on TreeTable of SAPUI5.

Maybe I misunderstand. Please help me clear.

This is the example of the data that I got from JSON.stringify.

```
[{"value":{"Id":"00145E5BB2641EE284F811A7907717A3",
"Text":"BI-RA                   Reporting, analysis, and dashboards",
"Parent":"00145E5BB2641EE284F811A79076F7A3","Type":"BMF"},
"children":[{"value":{"Id":"00145E5BB2641EE284F811A7907737A3",
"Text":"WebIntelligence_4.1","Parent":"00145E5BB2641EE284F811A7907717A3",
"Type":"TWB"},"children":[{"value":{"Id":"00145E5BB2641EE284F811A7907757A3",
"Text":"Functional Areas","Parent":"00145E5BB2641EE284F811A7907737A3","Type":"TWB"},
"children":[{"value":{"Id":"00145E5BB2641EE284F811A7907777A3",
"Text":"CHARTING","Parent":"00145E5BB2641EE284F811A7907757A3","Type":"TWB"},
"children":[{"value":{"Id":"001999E0B9081EE28AB706BE26631E93",
"Text":"Drill","Parent":"00145E5BB2641EE284F811A7907777A3","Type":"TWB"},
"children":[{"value":{"Id":"001999E0B9081EE28AB706BE26633E93",
"Text":"[AUTO][ACCEPT] Drill on charts DHTML","Parent":"001999E0B9081EE28AB706BE26631E93",
"Type":"TWB","Ref":"UT_WEBI_CHARTS_DRILL_HTML"}},{"value":{"Id":"001999E0B9081EE28AB706BE26635E93",
"Text":"[AUTO][ACCEPT] Drill on charts JAVA","Parent":"001999E0B9081EE28AB706BE26631E93",
"Type":"TWB","Ref":"UT_WEBI_CHARTS_DRILL_JAVA"}}]},...
```

The output that I want shouldn't be array of object but should be something like...

```
   {{"value":{
        "Id":"00145E5BB2641EE284F811A7907717A3",
        "Text":"BI-RA                   Reporting, analysis, and dashboards",
        "Parent":"00145E5BB2641EE284F811A79076F7A3","Type":"BMF"},
        "children":{
           {"value":{
                "Id":"00145E5BB2641EE284F811A7907737A3",
                "Text":"WebIntelligence_4.1",
                "Parent":"00145E5BB2641EE284F811A7907717A3",
                "Type":"TWB"},
                "children":{
                      {"value":{
                          "Id":"00145E5BB2641EE284F811A7907757A3",
                          "Text":"Functional Areas",
                          "Parent":"00145E5BB2641EE284F811A7907737A3",
                          "Type":"TWB"},...
```

Comment: it would be useful to know what kind of output you expected as well

Comment: Please study the [JSON syntax](http://www.json.org/).

Comment: The output you want is not legal JSON.  The double `{` is a dead give-away.  There must ALWAYS be a key value after the `{` (unless the object is empty).

Comment: You're getting the initial `[` because you're feeding the JSON stringifier an array.

Comment: And why would you NOT expect "children" to be an array????

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.stringify` merely converts JavaScript data structures to a JSON-formatted string for consumption by other parsers (including `JSON.parse`).  If you want it to stringify to a different value, you must change the source data structures first.

However, it seems that this can't be represented as anything other than an array because you have duplicate keys (i.e. `value` appears more than once).  That would not be valid for a JavaScript object or a JSON representation of such.

Comment: Actually, it stores the tree data. Each array contains parent, id, text,... of each node. And it has children:[value:...] that stores children of that node.

Comment: @user2335149 - It doesn't "store" anything.  It creates a string representation of the data.  Read the [JSON syntax](http://www.json.org/).

Comment: @HotLicks If json is string. Can I just replace "[" and "]" with "{" and "}"?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Yes, but it's very complicated. So I want to find other solution if possible.

Comment: @user2335149 - Yes, if you wish to destroy the JSON, you can do that replacement.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is

`JSON.stringify(data[0]);`

or perhaps

`JSON.stringify(data[0].value);`

where data is the object you passed in the question

Comment: Thanks for your reply but if you look inside, it contains many arrays not only the data[0].

Comment: Hmm.  If, and only if, all your arrays contain a single element, you could do something like remove the [] - seems kind of funny to do that, but if the hack works :  str.replace("[",""); str.replace("]","");